# Создание таблиц типа "MERGE"

Tags: mysql, sql

```
$sql_1="create table table_one (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
name char(20));";

$sql_1="create table table_two (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
name char(20))";

$sql_1="insert into table_one (name) values ('11'), ('22'), ('33')";
$sql_1="insert into table_two (name) values ('aa'), ('bb'), ('cc')";

$sql_1="create table summ_table (
id int not null auto_increment,
name char(20), index(id))
type=merge union=(table_one,table_two) insert_method=last";
```

Взято с [Типы и структура таблиц в MySQL](http://kbss.ru/blog/bd_mysql/82.html).
Почему ошибка

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=merge union=(table_one,table_two) insert_method=last' at line 4

У меня только догадки-может версия у меня не поддерживает эту функцию.

Comment: Помогло.Сделайте ответом ,чтобы закрыть.Unable to open underlying table which is differently defined or of non-MyISAM type or doesn't exist
типа phpAdmin не поддерживает их?

Comment: Это Вы о чём?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так `type=merge` или `engine=merge`?